# How to run SQL Server 2008 mdf file with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, windows-xp

I created a database with SQL Server Management Studio 2008 then I copied the `.mdf` file to my Visual Studio 2012 project but I'm getting compatibility errors. Is it possible to do it in this way?

I tried to add connection to server explorer but I'm getting the error below:

[image]

I think it is because of I copied the `.mdf` file but I'm not sure.

Why I want to add specific SQL Server 2008 `.mdf` file is because I want to run my code also in Windows XP and I found that XP supports only SQL Server 2008.

So what should I do in this case?

Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to use the `AttachDbFileName=xyz.mdf` feature in your code, then you **must** have SQL Server **Express** installed. This feature works **ONLY** in the Express edition

Comment: Normally that feature is working with mdf file v11. When I'm trying to add mdf file v10 I get an error with Visual Studio 2012.